# Each parent's div should have its own background. The path to the image is inside. How to do it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

how to make each block background was the same as the path on a picture.
I can not understand. Now all blocks is the general background

```js
   var width = document.documentElement.clientWidth,
     height = width / 3,
     bg = $('.views-field-nothing').find('.views').html();
   bg = "url('" + bg + "')";
    //$(".views-field-nothing").attr("<img src=", bg);

   $(".views-field-nothing").css('background', bg);

   $(".views-field-nothing").css('height', height);
   $(".views-field-nothing").css('width', width);
```

```css
.views-field-nothing {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="views-field-nothing">
  <div class="views">http://goodimg.ru/img/tsvetochek-risunok3.jpg</div>
</div>
<div class="views-field-nothing">
  <div class="views">http://agu-shop.ru/images/pink_flower_512x512.png</div>
</div>
<div class="views-field-nothing">
  <div class="views">http://www.raskraska.ru/counting/flower-bw.gif</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`js` at Question appears to set `background` of only first `.views-field-nothing` element.

Use `.each()` to iterate all `.views-field-nothing` : `bg` elements, set `width` and `height` `background` by utilizing selector `$(".views", this)` , `.html()` within loop

```js
var width = document.documentElement.clientWidth,
  height = width / 3,
  bg = $(".views-field-nothing");

bg.each(function() {
  $(this).css({
    background: "url(" + $(".views", this).html() + ")",
    height: height,
    width: width
  })
});
```

```css
.views-field-nothing {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="views-field-nothing">
  <div class="views">http://goodimg.ru/img/tsvetochek-risunok3.jpg</div>
</div>
<div class="views-field-nothing">
  <div class="views">http://agu-shop.ru/images/pink_flower_512x512.png</div>
</div>
<div class="views-field-nothing">
  <div class="views">http://www.raskraska.ru/counting/flower-bw.gif</div>
</div>
```